# MVC Hierarchical Routing

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

Are the following routes possible (and does it even make "MVC-sense") with ASP.NET MVC 5:

```
Organisations/3/Employees/7/Edit
```

Description:  From organisation of id 3, editing employee with id 7.

```
Organisations/3/Employees/Create
```

Description: Create a new employee for organisation 3.

Employees belong to organisations (they cannot exist without an organisation), which is why I like the hierarchical URL structure.  It resembles that of resources in a RESTful API design.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, I create a variant of these routes in most of my admin applications, they almost feel "fluent" the way they read.

Here is a quick sample of my route definitions how I would lay it out.

```
_routeCollection.MapRoute(null, 
  "Organisations/{organisationId}/Employees/{id}/edit", 
  new { controller = "Employee", action = "Edit" });

_routeCollection.MapRoute(null, 
  "Organisations/{organisationId}/Employees/create", 
  new { controller = "Employee", action = "Create" });
```

Then you employee controller actions Edit/Create would accept the organisationId parameter along with any other needed parameters to invoke those actions. I generally add this next route to handle the details of an object

```
_routeCollection.MapRoute(null, 
  "Organisations/{organisationId}/Employees/{id}", 
  new { controller = "Employee", action = "Detail" });
```

To create an Html.ActionLink you would call `@Html.ActionLink("Employee", "Edit", new { organisationId = 2, id = 10});`

Comment: That's great.  And how exactly would I create an `@Html.ActionLink(..)` to point to such a location?