# ASP.NET MVC 5 - Mapping controller route and proper way to map nested actions

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-mvc-routing

I have a controller called `Expense` that has the usual (default template generated) actions:

- `Expense/Index`
- `Expense/Create/{id}`
- `Expense/Details/{id}`
- `Expense/Edit/{id}`

I also have a controller called `Expense_Status`, whose actions (from default template with the addition of the `string serialNumber` and `Date month` parameters) are mapped to:

- `Expense/{serialNumber}/Status/{action}/{month}`, e.g. *Expense/123/Status/Edit/11-2020*

My ***App_Start/ RouteConfig.cs*** is as following:

```
    public class RouteConfig
    {
        public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
        {
            routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

            routes.Ignore(url: "Expense_Status{pathInfo}", constraints: new { pathInfo = "."});

            routes.MapMvcAttributeRoutes();

            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "ExpenseStatus",
                url: "Expense/{serialNumber}/Status/{action}/{month}",
                defaults: new { controller = "Expense_Status", action = "Index", month = UrlParameter.Optional }
                );

            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "Default",
                url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
                defaults: new {controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
            );
        }
    }
```

What I would like to know is:

1. How can I remove/ignore the path `Expense_Status/{action}/{id}` that matches the '***default***' mapping, and keep only `Expense/123/Status/Edit/11-2020` and similar paths?
2. Is this the proper way to map this kind of Objects since `Expense` has multiple `Statuses`? I saw this post [MVC Hierarchical Routing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24219988/mvc-hierarchical-routing) , I like that I can have the `Expense_Status` actions in the `Expense` controller, but do not like the fact that I have to '*hardcode*' all the actions as separate route mapping in the ***RouteConfig.cs***

I have tried adding the following to the ***RouteConfig.cs*** but did not solve question 1) :

```
routes.Ignore(url: "Expense_Status{pathInfo}", constraints: new { pathInfo = "."});
```

Expense_Status/etc.... is still accessible

---

Tried using the solution from this post [Exclude a Controller from Default Route C# MVC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26285326/exclude-a-controller-from-default-route-c-sharp-mvc) , but how can I exclude multiple controllers without writing multiple MapRoute -ings for each controller that I would like to exclude?

e.g.

```
routes.MapRoute(
                name: "Default",
                url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
                defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional },
                constraints: new NotEquals("Expense_Status")
            );

routes.MapRoute(
                name: "AnotherDefault",
                url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
                defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional },
                constraints: new NotEquals("<name_of_other_controller_to_exclude>")
            );
```

It seems like there is too much repetition and code pollution.

**EDIT 1:**
There is also the option of using Attribute Routing like so:

```
public class ExpenseController : Controller
{
    // eg: /Expense/123/Status/Edit/11-2020
    [Route(“Expense/{serialNumber}/Status/Edit/{month}”)]
    public ActionResult StatusEdit(string serialNumber, string month)
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

, but I do not like the fact that I have to specify the name of the controller in the route.